# How can I set/define the var type when using Array.from?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, types

The following will give me unique entries which is what I want from an array of string values string[].

```
const items: string[]= ["a","b","c","d","c","d"];
const uniqueItems = Array.from(new Set(items));
```

**Q: However, how do I define/specify the type for uniqueItems?**

```
const items: string[]= ["a","b","c","d","c","d"];
// This does not work
const uniqueItems: string[] = Array.from(new Set(items));
```

Error is:

*TS2322: Type {}[] is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
    Type '{} is not assignable to type 'string'*

vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv

Linux Information from ng --version

- Angular CLI: 6.2.9
- Node: 8.9.4
- Angular: 6.1.10
- Also, package typescript: 2.9.2

Comment: Seems to work fine [on the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/LAKAxg9gdgzgLgAgJZwKYFsYC4HwE5JQDmA2gLoC8CJARAIY0A0NARkzWOwCbufM9kA3KEixEAVyhIAjuNQBJNJhz5CpMgioBBPHjoBPAHQAzPBHQAKKKgDuCAMqo4FlBhgBKd8JBA).

Comment: Yup, code is fine even i checked, it would be great if you could share demo fiddle

Comment: My codebase is large and on a different network. I can see it working in the playground. Maybe its a version issue. I'll update my posting with the ng --version information.

Comment: @CRice are you aware of any version requirements for this to operate?

Comment: TypeScript is evolving rapidly, and TypeScript 2.9 is 2 years old. In TypeScript terms, that's like shortly after dinosaurs. There has been a significant amount of work on `Array` methods in 3.8 and 3.9, and probably also in between.

Comment: Try using generics like `Array.from(new Set<string>(items))` or `Array.from<string>(new Set<string>(items))`?

Comment: Interestingly, works on v2.4.1 [on the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=2.4.1&ssl=4&ssc=1&pln=3&pc=58#code/LAKAxg9gdgzgLgAgJZwKYFsYC4HwE5JQDmA2gLoC8CJARAIY0A0NARkzWOwCbufM9kA3KEixEAVyhIAjuNQBJNJhz5CpMgioBBPHjoBPAHQAzPBHQAKKKgDuCAMqo4FlBhgBKd8JBA).

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thank you very much. new Set<string>... resolved my issue. So others can see, post it for the answer.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I completely agree that it is a dinosaur. I don't get a say in things. They had me update it 6 months ago from Angular 5 to the latest 6. I was like why not go to 8.x?  They shut me down for all upgrades.

Comment: @HereticMonkey: Interestingly, it works in *every single version* on the playground, which has e.g. 2.8 and 3.0, so this seems to be specific to 2.9.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Awesome. Well, I guess if you're going to have a playground, you want to leave out the swing sets that are missing a few bolts ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve it by telling TypeScript what type of elements are in the `Set`, since apparently version 2.9.2 of TypeScript isn't properly inferring it.

```
const items: string[]= ["a","b","c","d","c","d"];
const uniqueItems: string[] = Array.from(new Set<string>(items));
```

Taking advantage of the generic form of `Set` defined in `lib`, we can tell TypeScript, "this is a set of strings, dammit" :).